# When selecting multiple days on the FullCalendar the cells don't highlight as selected until after a significant delay

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

When I am trying to select multiple days in a FullCalendar, cells are not getting highlighted immediately and it is highlighted after a significant delay. I've set selectLongPressDelay to 10 but still seeing the issue as the the delay is much more then 10 ms.
The version of full calendar I am using is
"@fullcalendar/core": "^4.4.2",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.4.1",
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.4.1",
"@fullcalendar/react": "^4.4.1",

```
<FullCalendar
        ref={calendarRef}
        id="calendar"
        contentHeight="auto"
        timeZone={timezone}
        views={views}
        defaultView="customView"
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
        header={{ left: 'title', center: '', right: 'prev,next' }}
        }
        defaultDate=payPeriod.startDate
        events={(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) => (isDate ? getData(fetchInfo, date.startDate, date.endDate, Alias, successCallback, failureCallback)
          : getReqCalendar(fetchInfo, Alias, successCallback, failureCallback))}
        }}
        selectable
        selectLongPressDelay={10}
        select={selectInfo => handleDateSelect(selectInfo, selectedDates, scheduleDateRanges, timezone)}
        selectConstraint={{ startTime: '00:00', endTime: '24:00' }}
      />
```

I tried removing selectLongPressDelay/ also decreasing the time from 10ms but nothing changed.